# Creating instance-vars in a loop returns None objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

I tried a small `trafficlight` implementation and got the following code:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.redLight = Light(color = "red", master = self.frame)     
    self.redLight.place(x = 10, y = 10)
    self.yellowLight = Light(color = "yellow", master = self.frame)
    self.yellowLight.place(x = 10, y = 40)
    self.greenLight = Light(color = "green", master = self.frame)
    self.greenLight.place(x = 10, y = 70)
    ...
```

I got bored and tried to define this pretty redundant code in a loop:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.redLight = None
    self.yellowLight = None
    self.greenLight = None

    for l in [[self.redLight, "red", 10],
              [self.yellowLight, "yellow", 40],
              [self.greenLight, "green", 70]]:
        l[0] = Light(color = l[1], master = self.frame)
        l[0].place(x = 10, y = l[2])
    ...
```

My understanding is, that it does exactly the same as the the first code example, but it turns out, that it does not write the instance variables. As I watched the code in the debugger, the `l[0]` object was a Light-object...

Isn't python call-by-reference, so the `l[0]` should directly write the instance variables?

Comment: `l[0]` is the list element at index 0, not the instance variable.

Comment: but this would not be a problem if python referenced it right? then ```l[0]``` would be (ref to) the same object as ```self.redLight```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) are for:

```
def __init__(self):
    for l in [['redLight', "red", 10],
              ['yellowLight', "yellow", 40],
              ['greenLight', "green", 70]]:
        setattr(self, l[0], Light(color=l[1], master=self.frame))
        getattr(self, l[0]).place(x=10, y=l[2])
```

Because as mentioned in the comments assigning to `l[0]` just changes the contents of the local variable `l` which **doesn't set** the attributes on your instance.

Note that this boils down to:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = a
>>> b = 2  # assigning a new value to "b" doesn't change "a"!
>>> a
1
```

or:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = [a]
>>> b[0] = 2  # won't change "a".
>>> a
1
```

So while you can change the attribute by assigning to `self.redLight` doesn't mean you can change the attribute by assigning a different value to a list that contains a reference to the value of `self.redLight`.

Comment: ty, is there a way to say python like you can do in c++ via pointer, that this is the same object so they will change (just asking from curiosity:D )?

Comment: Unfortunately (or rather fortunately) not. In some circumstances you can achieve similar results with mutable types and mutating them (for example if you change the `__dict__` attribute of `self`).

Comment: @Steelbean It's not exactly like pointers but you could also use `functools.partial` with `getattr` and `setattr` to "emulate" dynamic access. For example `rl = partial(getattr, self, 'redLight')` and then you can access `rl()` to get the current value of `self.redLight` and likewise `rls = partial(setattr, self, 'redLight')` and `rls(value)` to set `self.redLight`. But it still requires function calls so I don't know if that "counts as C++ like pointer operations". If you want I could add that as complete example in the answer.